# sinon stub a null property

Tags: javascript, mocking, sinon

In my real class, I have `this.widget = null`. It gets assigned later in the code, with an object.

During my test, I want to "assume" it was initialized. Meaning I want to stub `myInstance.widget` with whatever behavior is needed for the test.

However as far as I can see sinon does not let me stub methods that do not exist, even less so an object that doesn't exist.

Is there a different way?

i.e.
`sinon.stub(myInstance.widget,"doSomething").return("hello")`

where `myInstance.widget` is actually `null`

Comment: Can you assign a stub directly like `myInstance.widget = {doSomething: sinon.stub() }`?

Comment: But then it wouldn't revert the widget at the end of each test

Comment: Why not using  `afterEach(() => myInstance.widget = null)` to revert to original object?